# Is there anyway to use E4X in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, e4x

I am primarily an ActionScript programmer and I love working with XML using E4X. I also use PHP a lot but am currently too intimidated to process XML with PHP, I was wondering if there was a way to use E4X in PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=7843) might be approximately what you're looking for.

That said, you're probably better off using one of the native PHP XML-parsing methods. [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/simplexml) is probably your best bet.