# How to automate feed checking

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, feed

I know how to parse and setup databases etc in php. However i was wondering how would i go about constantly checking a xml feed for a specific string in one of the  tags and then every time this string is found adding the whole XML item( as in the   tags etc) to a database.

What i really need help on is how i would make my script constantly be working and looking out for these strings? It would need to refresh the xml feed every 20 minutes or so to keep a look
out for the string and then when it finds it add it to the database without me manually navigating to the php page every time.

So all i need is a idea on how this could be achieved?
If you could help me it would be great and much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have at the moment? Without any XML structure sample is hard to give provide a solution for the parsing.

Comment: I would not think you would need it, sorry. I don't need help on how to parse or the structure or even on any code really. Just on how i can set it up so it constantly checks for the string and if found, add's it to the database every 20 minutes. I do not need help with the actual code side of this. Just what do i do to make it so that i don't have to navigate to a php page every 20 minutes, it just does it automatically.

Comment: @ajreal Don't need any XML structure sample. It would be quite simple to return an node by looking for a string using e4x. What I don't know is if php supports/intergrates with e4x in someway.

Comment: I would recommend you look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761087/is-there-anyway-to-use-e4x-in-php

Comment: Thanks for your help, Im not sure i was completely clear. I can parse XML, i just need a way to constantly keep it updated and refreshing every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i really need help on is how i would make my script constantly be working and looking out for these strings? It would need to refresh the xml feed every 20 minutes or so

Execute the script using [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

(And make sure your script keeps a cache and respects [cache control headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/))

Comment: Great! So i can set up a schedule to execute a script every 20 minutes or so? Do any hosting provider's provide cron jobs built in? If so could you possibly recommend one. This is exactly what i needed!

Comment: @Api You really need to go and look for yourself. Different hosts provide different services, so there's no definitive answer to be had from anyone but yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure it was possible. I will look into this. Thanks Very much!